# SQL multiple join statement issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join, inner-join

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will retrieve a table (called CommsLog) and match it to a user table to return all the names that are associated with it.

The user database stores all the users by alias and then I am trying to look up their first and last name in the database, concatenate them and return that into my results

This is what I've got at the moment but it only returns part of the table and the same names for both columns (These should be different)

```
SELECT 
    CommsLog.ID, 
    CommsLog.CommType, 
    CommsLog.Date, 
    Users.FirstName +' ' + Users.LastName, 
    Users.FirstName +' ' + Users.LastName, 
    CommsLog.Version 
FROM CommsLog
INNER JOIN Users
ON CommsLog.SentTo=Users.Alias and CommsLog.SentFrom=.Users.Alias
```

**EDIT: Update with Data and output**

CommsLog table looks like:

```
+----+----------+--------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
| ID | CommType |           Date           |  SentTo  | SentFrom | Version |
+----+----------+--------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
| 12 | Test     | 2014-12-19 09:38:10.000  | uk\tmot  | uk\gmab  | 1.10    |
+----+----------+--------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

User table looks like:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------------+
|  Alias  | FirstName | LastName | Telephone  |              email               |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------------+
| uk\tmot | Tom       | motoll   | 0731424523 | tom.motoll@stackoverflow.com     |
| uk\gmab | Grant     | maberick | 0756463345 | grant.maberick@stackoverflow.com |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------------+
```

Ouput:

```
+----+----------+-------------------------+------------+----------------+---------+
| ID | CommType |          Date           |   SentTo   |    SentFrom    | Version |
+----+----------+-------------------------+------------+----------------+---------+
| 12 | Test     | 2014-12-19 09:38:10.000 | Tom motoll | Grant maberick | 1.10    |
+----+----------+-------------------------+------------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: can u proivde some sample data + ur desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to pull in both the names of the SentTo users as well as the names of the SentFrom users in your `SELECT` statement. If that's the case, then you're actually going to need to join your `USERS` table into your query twice, with aliases -- once for your SentTo users and once for your SentFrom users. Try this for a query, instead:

```
SELECT 
    CSLL.CommsLog.ID, 
    CSLL.CommsLog.CommType, 
    CSLL.CommsLog.Date, 
    UserTo.FirstName +' ' + UserTo.LastName, 
    UserFrom.FirstName +' ' + UserFrom.LastName, 
    CSLL.CommsLog.Version 
FROM CSLL.CommsLog
INNER JOIN CSLL.Users UserTo ON CSLL.CommsLog.SentTo=UserTo.Alias
INNER JOIN CSLL.Users UserFrom ON CSLL.CommsLog.SentFrom=UserFrom.Alias
```

Since you didn't post your table structure or any sample data, you may need to tweak that query a bit to make it work, but it should at least get you close to what you're after.

Comment: Brilliant thanks worked perfectly first time. I see where I'm going wrong now

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning to only get records that were sent from a user to themselves?
That is what your join condition is doing.